# Get correlations for all combinations between two differently sized dataframes

Tags: r, correlation

Is there an R function to calculate all possible correlations and provide p-values between rows in two data frames (with similar number of columns but varying rows), similar as to the `cor()` function in R?

I found `cor.test(`), but it only takes a dataframe of similar size.

Comment: Why do you want to get correlations for differently sized datasets? Also why not merge/cbind them. Are the two datasets related in some way?

Comment: I have a subset of "genes" with expression values in df1 (100 rows and 10 samples) and another subset of genes with expression in df2 (1000 rows and 10 samples samples). I want to make a row-wise corr.test against each row in df1 and each row in df2

Comment: OK, do we understand correctly that you want to do 100x1000 correlations of 10 data points in each sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the function `cor.test` only accepts vectors of numeric values that have the same length.

You can achieve what you are looking for with, e.g., the function `corrplot::cor.mtest`.

Here is a reproducible example. First load the library and create the fake data...

```
library(corrplot)

nbgene1 <- 100
nbgene2 <- 200
n <- 10

df1 <- matrix(rnorm(nbgene1 * n), nbgene1, n)
rownames(df1) <- paste0("Df1_gene", 1:nbgene1)
colnames(df1) <- paste0("Subject", 1:n)

df2 <- matrix(rnorm(nbgene2 * n), nbgene2, n)
rownames(df2) <- paste0("Df2_gene", 1:nbgene2)
colnames(df2) <- paste0("Subject", 1:n)
```

The function `cor.mtest` only accepts a *single* data-frame, with individuals as rows and variables as columns, so you need to combine the two data-frames...

```
df_combined <- rbind(df1, df2)
```

... and input the transposed data-frame to `cor.mtest` (because in your case, rows are genes and columns are individuals).

```
res_cortest <- cor.mtest(t(df_combined))
```

Then all you need to do is extract the correct p-values from the result.

```
pval <- res_cortest$p[1:nbgene1, (nbgene1+1):(nbgene1+nbgene2)]
```

You may want to rename the rows and columns of this matrix for a more interpretable result.

```
dimnames(pval) <- list(rownames(df1), rownames(df2))
```

Also, don't forget to correct for multiple testing !

```
# For example with Banjamini and Hochberg's method
padj <- matrix(p.adjust(pval, "BH"), nbgene1, nbgene2, dimnames = dimnames(pval))
```

---

What's even more interesting than using `cor.mtest` is to look at what's inside!

```
> corrplot::cor.mtest
function (mat, ...) 
{
    mat <- as.matrix(mat)
    n <- ncol(mat)
    p.mat <- lowCI.mat <- uppCI.mat <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    diag(p.mat) <- 0
    diag(lowCI.mat) <- diag(uppCI.mat) <- 1
    for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):n) {
            tmp <- cor.test(x = mat[, i], y = mat[, j], ...)
            p.mat[i, j] <- p.mat[j, i] <- tmp$p.value
            if (!is.null(tmp$conf.int)) {
                lowCI.mat[i, j] <- lowCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[1]
                uppCI.mat[i, j] <- uppCI.mat[j, i] <- tmp$conf.int[2]
            }
        }
    }
    list(p = p.mat, lowCI = lowCI.mat, uppCI = uppCI.mat)
}
```

It's a simple `for` loop!

An equivalent of this loop in the context of our reproducible example would be...

```
pval <- matrix(NA, nbgene1, nbgene2,
               dimnames = list(rownames(df1),
                               rownames(df2)))
for (i in 1:nbgene1) {
  for (j in 1:nbgene2) {
    pval[i, j] <- cor.test(df1[i, ], df2[j, ])$p.value
  }
}
```

The multiple correction step is the same.